# Css background/background-position problem

Tags: css, background, css-float

i have a problem with "position" of some code:

can anyone help me to find a correct solution to show the graphics at the right and left side and the "content" in the middle without the "white overflow"?

Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1qfeb.jpg

Source from file.html

```
<div id="toggler-1">
 <div class="box-2">
  <div class="left left-img">
  </div>
 <div class="left content">
  <p>simple text example ...</p>
 </div>
 <div class="right right-img">
 </div>
 <div class="clear">
 </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Source from CSS:

```
.content .main .box .box-2{height:100%;width:100%;background:#FFF}
.content .main .box .box-2 .left-img{background:url("../images/content-box-left-left.gif");background-repeat:repeat-y;width:14px;height:100%}
.content .main .box .box-2 .right-img{background:url("../images/content-box-right-right.gif");background-repeat:repeat-y;width:14px;height:100%}
.content .main .box .box-2 .content{text-align:left;color:#000000;vertical-align:top}
```

Comment: You want to eliminate the white background from the center, is that correct?  So behind the "Simple text example" should be the gray background image? Sorry, it's not completely clear what you mean by "without the \"white overflow\"?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#wrapper
 {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 922px;
 }

#leftcolumn
{ 
 display: inline;
 color: #333;
 margin: 10px;
 padding: 0px;
 width: 195px;
 float: left;
}

#content
{ 
 float: left;
 color: #333;
 margin: 10px 13px;
 padding: 0px;
 width: 460px;
 display: inline;
 position: relative;
}

#rightcolumn
{ 
 display: inline;
 position: relative;
 color: #333;
 margin: 10px 10px 10px 0px;
 padding: 0px;
 width: 195px;
 float: right;
}

And the HTML for this css is like

```
    <div id="wrapper">

        <div id="leftcolumn">



        </div>
        <div id="content">

        </div>
        <div id="rightcolumn">



        </div>
    </div>

</body>
```

It is best practice to wrap your all sub DIV into one outer DIV like wrapper DIV in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the background colour to transparent, to ensure that the containers aren't inheriting a white background from another rule...

```
.content .main .box .box-2{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    background:#FFF;
}

.content .main .box .box-2 .left-img{
    background-color: transparent;
    background:url("../images/content-box-left-left.gif");
    background-repeat:repeat-y;
    width:14px;
    height:100%;
}

.content .main .box .box-2 .right-img{
    background-color: transparent;
    background:url("../images/content-box-right-right.gif");
    background-repeat:repeat-y;
    width:14px;
    height:100%;
}

.content .main .box .box-2 .content{
    text-align:left;
    color:#000000;
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

Comment: hello Sohnee, the problem is still there so the transparent tag make no difference :(

Comment: It's a tough one to solve as I don't have your two images... any chance you can put them somewhere so I can test using them?

Answer (score 0):

i have a solution - for interested people here:

```
<div id="toggler-1">
 <div class="lo">
  <div class="ro"> 
   <div class="inhalt"> 
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit</p>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

and the css:

```
.content .main .box .ro {background:url(../images/content-box-right-right.gif) top right repeat-y;}
.content .main .box .lo {background:url(../images/content-box-left-left.gif) top left repeat-y;}
.content .main .box .inhalt {margin:0;padding:2.5em 2.5em 3.5em 2.5em;}
.content .main .box .inhalt p {margin:0;padding:0;}
```